# How to make the command option/switch of javadoc persistent under Windows?

Tags: java, javadoc

Because I am not using the English edition of Windows XP,I'll need to type:

> javadoc -locale en_US -version -author xxx.java

to produce what I want.The question is how to avoid typing these switch the next time I run javadoc?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My usual answer is to write a batch script:

```
@echo off
javadoc -locale en_US -version -author %*
```

...and then use that instead of `javadoc`. (The `%*` passes through all of the command-line options given to the batch file.)

Answer (score 1):

Put it in a batch file, and call the batch instead?

```
$ type myjavadoc.cmd

@"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\javadoc.exe" -locale en_US -version -author %*
```